# Leap Motion C++ Libraries not being recognized?

Tags: c++, dll, visualizer, leap-motion

I've been playing around with the leap motion using Java and it was fine.. but then I am trying to use C++ instead, but I couldn't seem to make this to work. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and set the libraries and include directory properly.
Despite, I always end up with this error:

```
1>Sample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: virtual __thiscall Leap::Interface::~Interface(void)" (__imp_??1Interface@Leap@@MAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __thiscall Leap::FingerList::~FingerList(void)" (??1FingerList@Leap@@UAE@XZ)
```

This is just one of the errors, but I end up with 50(which means the LeapMotion is not recognizing any function, though the visualizer indeed shows data).

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know leap-motion, but did you also set the addional dependencies under project settigns->linker->input? Setting the library directory may not be sufficient.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Alexander is right, you need to specify the exact lib files you are using under project settings->linker->input to suppress the linker errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.
I set the libraries and include folder plus the input lib file but kept getting the errors (unresolved symbol) because the debug mode I had set.
You have to choose between Win32 or x64 and use the specific library provided in the Leap SDK.
That solved the problem.
Although my machine is 64-bit, on Configuration Manager I have Debug Win32 because I am using Cinder as well, not only the Leap Motion device.

Answer (score 0):

For others stumbling on this problem, there is more documentation on setting up Leap Motion projects in Visual Studio here:

https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/Languages/C++/Guides/Leap_C++_Development.html